# Json to Excel Export with alternate Row Colors as well as Filter on Header

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel

I am trying to find a solution which allows me to style / format my Excel files to have filters on column header rows as well as alternate row colors for the data.
I tried 'node-excel-export' module as it allows some styling but have not found 
a way to set background for full row on odd or even or how to add the filter boxes to header. I also tried json2xls but that fell short based on fact that i found no way to go and specify a different name for header other then the field name in db which is not always user friendly.

Any other modules which might help in achieving my goal ?

Comment: You can try jsreport-xlsx

Comment: Thanks but that's like shooting a pigeon with a tank

Comment: How about this https://github.com/pofider/html-to-xlsx